# can I use interface as service endpoint interface while using wsgen to generate my WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

can I use interface as service endpoint interface while using wsgen to generate my WSDL?

When I try doing so I get the error:- 
The class "com.nimble.sample.Calc" is not an endpoint implementation class.

CXF works fine but this problem comes only while using JAX-WS

Answer (score 0):

It's a known (old) issue still needs fixing. See:
https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-817